# How to Apply Regular Expression to BeautifulSoup with Python using find_All()

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape a website with multiple pages.
Each page has multiple `</table>` tags with ids ranging from 19 to 29. the number of tables on each page is random

Here is an example:

**page 1 HTML**

```
<table id='table20'>...</table>
<table id='table25'>...</table>
```

**page 2 HTML**

```
<table id='table19'>...</table>
<table id='table21'>...</table>
<table id='table29'>...</table>
```

**page 3 HTML**

```
<table id='table19'>...</table>
<table id='table20'>...</table>
<table id='table21'>...</table>
```

....

**page n HTML**

```
<table id='table19'>...</table>
```

I am trying to isolate these tables from the html pages, in order to scrape them. So far, I am able to loop through each page, but the regex that I wrote in order to extract the tables from each page don't seem to work. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
tables = soup.find_all('table', id = re.compile('^table\d(19|2[0-9])'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex expression `'table[12]\d'` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9TIr0U/1)):

```
data = '''<table id='table19'><tr></tr></table>
<table id='table20'><tr></tr></table>
<table id='table21'><tr></tr></table>

<table id='table40'><tr></tr></table>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for table in soup.find_all('table', {'id':re.compile(r'table[12]\d')}):
    print(table)
```

Prints:

```
<table id="table19"><tr></tr></table>
<table id="table20"><tr></tr></table>
<table id="table21"><tr></tr></table>
```

EDIT: For table 19 or 20-29 use non-capturing group ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9TIr0U/2)):

```
for table in soup.find_all('table', {'id':re.compile(r'table(?:19|2\d)')}):
    print(table)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. `soup.find_all('table', {'id':re.compile(r'table(?:19|2\d)')})` does exactly what I was looking for. Magnificient, brilliant solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If that id start string is unique to the tables of interest could you not use attribute = value css selector and starts with operator?

```
for table in soup.select('table[id^=table]'):
    #do something with table
```

Comment: QHarr, Thanks for your contribution. Andrey's answer helped me.

Comment: I didn't try it because I don't think it takes into account, the fact that I was looking to select only tables with itds that are between 19 and 29 (table19, table20,...). But let me try it and get back to you on that.

Comment: Ok. Cos the way it reads _Each page has multiple </table> tags with ids ranging from 19 to 29._  implies that there are only ids 19-29 so other numbers are not a consideration.

Comment: then if each id begins with table and those ids only occur for the tables of interest the above should work and be more efficient, Only one way to find out though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197068/discussion-between-alljs-and-qharr).